# Winforms ComboBox strange behaviour

Tags: winforms, debugging, combobox

I'm setting a `DataSource` of a `ComboBox`

```
 comboBox.DataSource = new string[2]{"a", "b"};
```

Then I'm setting a `SelectedIndex`

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

It throws an exception : `InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.`
The exact code:

```
ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox
{
    DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList,
    Left = currentValueLeft,
    Top = currentTop + height + DEFAULT_MARGIN,
    Height = txtvalue.Height,
    Width = txtvalue.Width,
    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
};
comboBox.DataSource = new string[2] { "a", "b" };
comboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
pnall.Controls.Add(comboBox);
```

I debugged and realized that the debugger shows me there are 0 items present.
What it the reason for such behaviour?

Comment: Works for me.  Where in the code are you setting it?

Comment: I'm setting a `DataSource` to 2-element array and then set `SelectedIndex` to 1, but it throws an exception, telling "1" is not a valid index, so i debugged and realized that there are no items.

Comment: You have to post code that duplicates the problem.  Right now, I get a ComboBox with a, b, c as my choices.

Comment: Sounds like you have two different combo boxes, or else you're setting DataSource to something else later, or possibly the code in your question is never actually executed. We need to see enough of your code to rule out (or in) those possibilities.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: That still doesn't duplicate the problem because the code you posted still works...for us.

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: You need to assign the control somewhere, there is no container for the control so it is never intitialized.  pnall.Controls.Add(comboBox); then set the source and index

Comment: Yes, i'm adding a `ComboBox` to a panel later in the code, but the it ins't modified anywhere else.

Comment: You can't set the SelectedIndex property until after it's added to the panel.

Comment: Thx for the hint. I added a `ComboBox` to a `Panel` before any modifications and the code seem to work.